# Button.setOnClickListener ссылается на нулевой объект

Tags: android, android-viewpager, setonclicklistener

У меня есть класс customView. этот класс является одним из представлений viewPager. Я хочу, чтобы вся логика, связанная с управлением ViewPager, была в одном месте: PagerAdapter, а не в нескольких местах.Я попыталась сделать это, но получила исключение: `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference` Я думаю, это исключение из-за того, что я вызываю `buttonToNextView.setOnClickListener (onNextButtonClickListener)` (в классе CustomView) перед инициализацией `onNextButtonClickListener`. Но я не знаю, как это исправить.

CustomView class:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Button button;
    private OnClickListener clickListener;
 
    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true);
        button = v.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    public void setClickListener(OnClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }
```

adapter class:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private View.OnClickListener clickListener;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

      clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("debug", "works");
            }
        };
    }

    public void setCustomView(CustomView customView) {
        customView.setClickListener(clickListener);
    }
.........
```

activity:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;
    private CustomView customView;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       customView = new CustomView(this);
        customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
        customPagerAdapter.setCustomView(customView);

    }
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException говорит прямо о том что элемент (в данном примере это `Button`) = null, Из этого вопрос `View v` не равно `null`? И `R.layout.custom_view` содержит `R.id.button`?

Comment: @ Tiarait , `View v` не равно `null` и `R.layout.custom_view` содержит `R.id.button`